# how to make query in laravel 7

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

i have query in my sql like this

```
SELECT villages.id FROM gocement.villages LEFT JOIN gocement.districts ON villages.district_id = districts.id Where villages.name = 'kebonagung' && districts.name ='sukodono';
```

from mysql i got the data village.id = 81

'kebonagung' it is can change using row['kelurahan'] from my code here

```
 $village_name = $row['kelurahan'];
            $district_name = $row['kecamatan'];
            $query = Village::select('villages.*');
            $query->leftJoin('districts', 'villages.district_id', '=', 'districts.id');
            $query->where('villages.name', '=', $village_name);
            $query->where('districts.name', '=', $district_name);
            $hasil = $query->get('villages.id');
            dd($hasil);
```

here what i have try using laravel code.

but when i run my laravel i got like this :

[image]
my question is how to fix my queries in my laravel code to get 81

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
 $query = Village::select('villages.id');
```

also change

```
$hasil = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

see this

```
$query = Village::select('villages.id');
        $query->leftJoin('districts', 'villages.district_id', '=', 'districts.id');
        $query->where('villages.name', '=', $village_name);
        $query->where('districts.name', '=', $district_name);
        $hasil = $query->pluck('id');
        dd($hasil->all()[0]);
```

it will return exactly 81